# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when requesting HTML content from php

Tags: php, apache, wamp

#### Issue

When sending a request to a PHP script I am receiving net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET if the content is a moderate size. This script works fine on all of my smaller files, but blows up with that error on my larger files.

#### PHP Script

```
<?php
include('Parsedown.php');
function update($url){
        set_time_limit(0);
        $prefix="/doc/";
        $Parsedown = new Parsedown();
        $body = file_get_contents(str_replace($prefix, "", $url, $count));
        $content = $Parsedown->text($body);
        echo $content;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
   switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
    case 'update':
        $path = $_REQUEST['path'];
        update($path);
    break;
 }
}
?>
```

I am using WAMP on my local machine and I have no errors inside of my PHP error log.

#### Apache Logs

```
 D:/DevelopmentPrograms/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:44.492523 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1100
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:45.098933 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1100:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:49.007005 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00428: Parent: child process 1100 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:49.162014 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:49.162014 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:49.162014 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00094: Command line:  'D:\\DevelopmentPrograms\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d    D:/DevelopmentPrograms/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:49.164014 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7256
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:49.755828 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7256:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:50.937481 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00428: Parent: child process 7256 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:51.107491 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:51.108491 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:51.108491 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\DevelopmentPrograms\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/DevelopmentPrograms/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:51.110491 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6848
[Mon Jul 27 22:04:51.705702 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6848:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jul 27 22:06:44.944044 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00428: Parent: child process 6848 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jul 27 22:06:45.187653 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 27 22:06:45.187653 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Jul 27 22:06:45.187653 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\DevelopmentPrograms\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/DevelopmentPrograms/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Jul 27 22:06:45.187653 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8060:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8908
[Mon Jul 27 22:06:45.841664 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8908:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: I went into Windows Event Viewer and this is what I found.

`Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.9.0, time stamp: 0x53258cd5
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.5.12.0, time stamp: 0x53614545
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000139344
Faulting process id: 0x1720
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0c8e57ed9d544
Faulting application path: D:\DevelopmentPrograms\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: D:\DevelopmentPrograms\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php5ts.dll
Report Id: bceb2687-34d8-11e5-bae9-00248c605386`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by running the 32-bit version of WAMP instead of 64-bit.